# Error 'type' of undefined while loading dynamic component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to render dynamic components based on the `type` field from the `mock.ts` file

Below is the structure of the mock,

```
export const Mock = {
  data: {
    areas: [
      {
        sections: [
          {
            rjf: [
              {
                type: 'heading-1',
                depth: 0,
                text: 'Heading Component',
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            rjf: [
              {
                type: 'paragraph',
                depth: 0,
                text: 'This is a paragraph',
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            rjf: [
              {
                type: 'heading-1',
                depth: 0,
                text: 'Heading Component',
              },
              {
                type: 'paragraph',
                depth: 1,
                text: 'This is a paragraph',
              },
              {
                type: 'paragraph',
                depth: 1,
                text: 'This is a paragraph',
              },
              {
                type: 'paragraph',
                depth: 1,
                text: 'This is a paragraph',
                inlineStyleRanges: [{
                  style:'BOLD',
                  offset: 83,
                  length: 16,
                }],
                inlineEntityRanges: [
                  {
                    type: 'LINK',
                    offset: 83,
                    length: 16,
                    data: {
                      target: '_self',
                      url: '/index.htm'
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Based on the Above mock, my `component.ts` look's like this,

```
  constructor() {
    Mock.data.areas.forEach((val) => {
      this.content = val.sections;
    });;
  }
```

And then, I'm send the content data to `hostComponent` via `@input`, and below is the code for rending the component

```
  private renderReactiveContent(content, container: ViewContainerRef) {
    let type: Type<any>;
    if (content && Object.keys(content).length > 0) {
      Object.keys(content).forEach((key: string) => {
        const values = content[key].rjf;
        if (content instanceof Array) {
          type = this.contentMappings[values[0].type];
        } else {
          type = this.contentMappings[values.type];
        }
        if (!type) {
          return;
        }
      });
    }

    const componentFactory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
    const component = container.createComponent(componentFactory);
    component.instance.contentOnCreate(content);

    // render embedded content
    if (content && Object.keys(content).length > 0) {
      Object.keys(content).forEach((key: string) => {
        const value = content[key];
        if (value instanceof Array) {
          value.forEach((v) => {
            this.renderReactiveContent(v, container);
          });
        } else {
          this.renderReactiveContent(value, container);
        }
      });
    }
    component.hostView.detectChanges();
  }
```

**So What is the issue here ?**

I'm getting `Error: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` in console.

What I'm doing wrong here ? Please guide me.

I've also, Created a working prototype Please refer to the below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anhm5k?file=src/app/render/content-host.component.ts

Comment: I just ran your stackblitz and there were no errors.

Comment: Sorry wrong link, I just updated my question

Comment: Aren't you treating the content param of renderReactiveContent() method as object? I see it's an array as assigned in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Put this condition

```
 const values = content[key].rjf;
    if (content instanceof Array) {
      if(this.contentMappings[values[0]]){
        type = this.contentMappings[values[0].type];
      }
    } else { ....
```

Also add this

```
if(type){
const componentFactory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
const component = container.createComponent(componentFactory);
component.instance.contentOnCreate(content);

// render embedded content
if (content && Object.keys(content).length > 0) {
  Object.keys(content).forEach((key: string) => {
    const value = content[key];
    if (value instanceof Array) {
      value.forEach((v) => {
        this.renderReactiveContent(v, container);
      });
    } else {
      this.renderReactiveContent(value, container);
    }
  });
}
component.hostView.detectChanges();
}
}
```

Comment: it dosen't work, its unable to find the component , it throws this error `      if(this.contentMappings[values[0]]){
        type = this.contentMappings[values[0].type];
      }`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood after going through your code, you are parsing the JSON wrong in renderReactiveContent(content,..) method. content is of type array, you are treating it as object. If you see the code below, it parses your content param correctly.  Error: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined is not there anymore.

```
 let type: Type<any>;

if (content && content.length > 0) {
  content.forEach((item: any) => {
    let objKey = Object.keys(item);
    const values = item['rjf'];

    if (values instanceof Array) {
      type = this.contentMappings[values[0].type];

    } else {
      type = this.contentMappings[values.type];

    }
    if (!type) {
      return;
    }
  });
   console.log(type);
}
```

However there is another error of "dynamic components not being defined in entryComponent property of NgModule". I see you are trying to create dynamic components using JSON. To create dynamic components you must mention them in entryComponents. How are you doing that?